# Calling sproc from LINQ with an xml parameter

Tags: sql, xml, linq, stored-procedures

There is an existing sproc that for the purposes of this experiment I do not want to change. It is currently called via a non-linq method like a sqlcommand and takes an xml parameter.

**Current implementation (Non-Linq)**

An xml fragment eg:

```
"<someTag>1</someTag><someTag>2</someTag>"
```

is passed to the sproc as a string.  Notice that it does not have a containing root element like

```
<someTags>.
```

In this implementation the sproc happily accepts this xml fragment as a string and works

**LINQ implementation**

If i try and call this sproc from LINQ then LINQ demands that i must use an Xelement.  Unfortunately the current xml fragment cannot be added to a Xelement because an Xelement  cannot have multiple roots.

If I add a root element the sproc will not work.

**What do i want**

I already know that i can change the xpath in the sproc to make it work in both scenarios.  I don't want to do this though

Hence, is it possible to have LINQ generate a parameter for this sproc that is not a Xelement without manually modifying the generated code?

OR

Is it possible to have an Xelement with multiple roots (i doubt it, but hey it's worth a shot)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need one XElement with multiple roots? You can generate the string input to your stored procedure from an `IEnumerable<XElement>` by using the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218%28VS.90%29.aspx) extension method.

If you can get an IEnumerable output from your LINQ query, you could then do

```
IEnumerable<XElement> someTags; 
//someTags = your LINQ query here;
string aggregatedTags = someTags.Aggregate(string.Empty, 
    (accumulator, someTag) => string.Concat(accumulator, someTag));
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,  The generated "LINQ to SQL" code wants a XElement and if possible I don't want to change generated code.  The sproc is an existing one used and requires the XML with multiple roots so that the xpath in it works.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're stuck making a change to the stored procedure, or possibly a change to the generated code. The only possibilities I can think of are:

1. Change the stored procedure to work with valid XML (one root).
2. Change the stored procedure to accept text input and just send the bad xml as a string (like user347805 suggests).
3. Create a partial class off your generated database code and make some way to have the stored procedure accept text. I'm not sure if this is even possible (probably isn't), but it may be worth looking into if for whatever reason you absolutely can't modify the stored procedure.

Why is it a big deal to change the stored procedure with such a small fix (a fix that should be made for clarity anyway)?